# I want to display grid but not the labels when using AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

What i want is a line chart that on the x-axis goes from 0 to 15 and has vertical grid lines on every integer from 0 to 15. I don't want any labels or legends or titles.

Code snippet:

```
//don't want legend showing
mRenderer.setShowLegend(false);

//this is the only way i can force it to have grid lines every integer (note: if i make this number 14 then the graph puts only 8 labels ie 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14)
mRenderer.setXLabels(15);

//this removes all labels from y axis
mRenderer.setYLabels(0);

//i have to do this otherwise the setShowGridY statement is worthless
mRenderer.setShowLabels(true);

//i do want a grid on the y-plane (not x-plane)
mRenderer.setShowGridY(true);

//forces x axis to span from 0 to 15    
mRenderer.setXAxisMax(15);
mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
```

What this code does is show grid lines and labels.  I only want gridlines but if i do this:
   mRenderer.setShowLabels(false);
then the labels dissapear as well as the gridlines.

It seems to me that you can only have gridlines if labels are enabled.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: What id did was replace mRenderer.setShowGridY(true) with mRenderer.setShowGrid(true) and then set mRenderer.setShowLabels(false) and it worked.

Comment: it does have the side effect of removing the title from the display but that isn't an issue right now.

Comment: now what do i do - Swetha Kini answered my questions but i don't know how to select his answer?

Comment: Now you can accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `renderer.setShowGrid(true)` instead of `setShowGridY(true)`